# Change button text (or div) at certain time every week

Tags: javascript

This is a bit hard to explain but I have a button that says 'offline', what I want it to do is automatically change to say 'online' between 7-9 every Friday night but at 9 it needs to switch back to 'offline' again.

Is there some sort of JavaScript solution? I haven't tried any code yet as I wouldn't be sure where to begin.

Appreciate any advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use getDay() and getHour(). Here's an example:

- If **getDate()** is 5 this means it's Friday
- If **getHour()** is between 19 and 21 this means between 7-9 pm

```js
var today = new Date();
var element = document.getElementById('status')
if(today.getDay() == 5 && (today.getHours() >= 19 && today.getHours() <= 21)){
    element.innerHTML = 'online';
}else{
    element.innerHTML = 'offline'
}
```

```html
<button id="status"></button>
```

Comment: Fantastic thanks. Now is it possible to apply one class when it's online and one when it isn't? I was thinking a red button when offline and green when on.

Comment: Its ok, I added the HTML into the innerHTML so worked it out. Thanks.

Comment: @jfar_2020 you can add a class like this: element.classList.add("myclass") andn remove it like this: element.classList.remove("myclass"). Glad it helped :).

Answer (score 0):

JS has an inbuilt Date function you can use

```
var time = new Date();
var hours = time.getHours()
var day = time.getDay()
if ((hours > 18 && hours < 22) && day == 5) {
  // do stuff with button
}
```

Although you may want this to run on an interval so if someone is on the website at 8:58 and they have it loaded until 9:02 it will turn off at 9:00 still

```
setInterval(() => { 
  var time = new Date();
  var hours = time.getHours()
  var day = time.getDay()
  if ((hours > 18 && hours < 22) && day == 5) {
    // do stuff with button
  }
}, 1500); // every 15 secs checks this
```

Heres some reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date